# gem "rack-cors" not working and request from angular client to rails api throwing cors error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby, http-status-code-422, rack-cors

I am struggling to get gem "rack-cors" to work locally. I have bare rails setup with gem 'devise_token_auth' and angular 7 client with 'angular-token' for auth. But every request from angular is throwing cors error. I have configured rails and "rack-cors" as per documentation but its not working. Here's my configuration in `application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
          headers: :any,
          expose: ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
          methods: [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
      end
    end
```

If I list Middlewares using `rails middleware`, `Rack::Cors` is listed second after `use Webpacker::DevServerProxy` but every request throws following error.

```
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"session"=>{}}
HTTP Origin header (http://localhost:4200) didn't match request.base_url (http://localhost:3000)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to change how protect_from_forgery was handled as mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/app/controllers/application_controller.rb.tt)

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

PS: To the person who deleted his answer, please don't do that, knowing what not to do is also part of leaning.

Comment: **Be warned:** this is a terrible idea (in OP's case - note they are using HTML). By doing this you are turning off a key security feature in Rails, which exposes you to CSRF.

Comment: @jakenberg I am using JSON API so its not an issue.

Comment: JSON APIs can still be vulnerable to CSRF via XSS: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/150877/40855. Update your question so that it doesn't show you rendering as HTML if this is a JSON API question.